# POST http://localhost:4200/addTask 404 (Not Found) in Angular2 and node js but values are printing in console

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CharityService} from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [CharityService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  [x: string]: any;

      fname  : string;
      lname  : string;
      age    : string;
      address: string;
      city   : string;



      constructor(private charityService:CharityService){
  /*         this.taskService.getTasks()
              .subscribe(tasks => {
                  console.log(tasks);
              });  */
      }

      addTask(event : any){

           var tasks = {
               fname   : this.fname,
               lname   : this.lname,
               age     : this.age,
               address : this.address,
               city    : this.city
           }

           console.log(event , tasks);
           //console.log(this.userForm.value);
               this.charityService.addTask(tasks).subscribe(data => {
                   console.log('Successful')
               })
       }
}
```

app.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CharityService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {} 


    addTask(tasks){
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/addTask', JSON.stringify(tasks), { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var task = require('../models/model')
//var Model = require('../models/model.js');

router.post('/addTask', function(request, response) {
    var task = new Model(request.body);
    task.save(function(err, resource) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(err).status(501);
        } else {
            response.json(resource).status(201);
        }
    });
}); 


module.exports = router;
```

model.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
/* var Schema= mysql.Schema;

var CharitySchema = new Schema({
    fname   : String,
    lname   : String,
    age     : String,
    address : String,
    city    : String
});

var Model = mysql.Model('task',CharitySchema);

module.exports = Model; */

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'charity_project'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... nn");    
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");    
    }
});

module.exports.addTask = function(tasks, callback) {
    connection.query("INSERT INTO registration SET ?", tasks, callback);
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 align="center"><u>Registration Form</u></h2> 


<br>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addTask($event)" >

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='fname' name="fname"  required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='lname' name="lname"  required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="age">Age:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='age' name="age"  required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='address' name="address"  required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='city' name="city"  required>
            </div>
        </div>

           <br>
           <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

server.js

```
var express    = require('express');
var morgan     = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var path       = require('path');

var mainRouter = require('./routes/index');
var apiRouter = require('./routes/api');


var app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));






app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use((express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src'))));

app.use('/', mainRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);


port = process.env.PORT || 4200;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("listening to port " + port);
})
```

No deploying errors.
But in here, when I input data it prints on Console. But it will not direct to the data base. It displays http://localhost:4200/addTask 404 (Not Found). Also it shows 
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: "↵↵↵Cannot POST /addTask↵↵↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: the route addTask exist in nodejs. 4200 is the port for angular. not for nodejs.

Comment: Are you using angular cli’s inbuilt server? Or have you integrated angular into express ?

Comment: I'm using Angular CLI inbuilt server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try for http://localhost:4200/api/addTask, as you are appending api in the route at `app.use('/api', apiRouter);`

I assume, You are using angular cli for angular development and running your angular project via `ng serve`. If this is true, then you can't keep node js application port as 4200. Since, angular cli uses it by default, till we don't configure it to use some other port.

My suggestion will be that you choose, some other port no for your node js app.

The new url should be `http://localhost:<new-port>/api/addTask`

Hope you have done CORS configuration, if not please put the below code in your node js app index.js

`app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});`

Comment: I did that. But the same result.  POST http://localhost:4200/api/addTask 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you add more detail, like how you are running angular and node content together in app? I mean are you serving angular compiled content in node.

Comment: I'm not using external packages like Fire base. use only URLs

Comment: Used dependencies are express,ejs,morgan,body-parser and mysql

Comment: I am very new to this angular. So I don't know much about this. That's why I cannot understand the questions. This is the very first thing I have done by looking several tutorials

Comment: Great! that is better than earlier I had. I used 2 port for angular and node. But now an error comes, OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/addTask net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: as mentioned earlier please use localhost:3000/api/addTask and look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

in express router you define **localhost:4200/api/addTask** and in you angular call to **localhost:4200/addTask**